# How to parse variable number of command line arguments in python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm new to python and want to handle variable number of arguments for a python code such that a string like this can be handled -

```
python abc.py -20 input1.txt input2.txt .. output.txt
```

-20 is optional. There has to be at least one input file, but there can be any number of those and a necessary output file at the end. I looked at argparse, and I can do fixed arguments or optional but unable to figure it out for this case.

Comment: what does the `-20` signify?  With something this simple, just looking at `sys.argv` might be good enough ...

Comment: Must the interface work exactly like this?  It will be ugly to do it exactly like this with `argparse`, but if you don't mind to change the CLI into a more standard format, it will be easy.

Comment: yup, sys.srgv worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `nargs='+'` for variable number arguments.

```
parser.add_argument("input", nargs='+')
parser.add_argument("output")

$ ./test.py input1 input2 input3 output
Namespace(input=['input1', 'input2', 'input3'], output='output')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use argparse. Here's an example from [argparse docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Run:

```
$ prog.py 1 2 3 4
4

$ prog.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10
```